# How to find number of vertices in a given graph?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I am studying on the graphs where eccentricity of every vertex is same. If $G$ is such graph where eccentricity is $r$
for every vertex and for a vertex $x$
if there exists at least two vertices such that $d(x,y) = d(x,z) =r$, then how to find number of vertices in the graph.

***My attempt:***

I considered two shortest paths $P$ and $P'$ between $x$ and $y$, and $x$ and $z$, respectively, such that lengths of these 
paths is $r$. So, total number of vertices traversed is $2r+2$ but the vertex $x$ is common, so finally I came to the conclusion
that the graph has at least 2r+1 vertices, i.e., $n\geq 2r+1$.

Is my procedure true? Am I missing any important fact? Kindly help. Any hint or suggestion is welcome.. Thanks for the help.

What if some vertices are repeated. I am not getting any idea. Kindly help.

Comment: It seems ok to me. Also, to check that your bound cannot be improved, note that you can achieve equality with a cyclic graph, and increase the number of vertices arbitrarily by choosing a node $u$ in the cycle, take its to neighbors $v,w$, and connect arbitrarily many nodes $u_i$ "above $u$" by introducing the paths $v-u_i-w$, $i=1,2,3,\ldots$. So it seems the inequality cannot be changed.

Comment: So, according to you my bound is correct?

Comment: I think so, yes. Moreover, it is a "best possible" bound too, per the constructions in my previous comments. Then again, I might have missed something as well, without realizing it…might be nice with some additional input from others…

Comment: Hmm…could these shortest paths between x,y,z coincide at some nodes for example? There might be more still to do…

Comment: That is the point where my doubt arises and hence the question. It is very much possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a graph with the property that each vertex has eccentricity $r$ and assume $G$ has $n$ vertices.
First we show that $G$ has no cut vertex.

Suppose $v$ is a cut vertex. Let $x$ be a vertex with $d(v,x)=r$.
$x$ is in some component $X$ of $G-x$.
Let $Y$ be another component of $G-x$ and $y\in Y$.
Then the path from $y$ to $x$ must pass through $v$, so $d(y,x)>d(v,x)=r$. Contradiction.

Now for vertex $v$ and integer $t\geq0$ let $S(v,t)$ be the set of vertices at distance exactly $t$ from $v$.
Clearly $|S(v,0)|=1$ and $|S(v,t)|\geq1$ for all $n\in\{1,\ldots,r\}$.
If $|S(v,t)|=1$ for some $t\in\{1,\ldots,r-1\}$, say $S(v,t)=\{w\}$, then $w$ is a cut vertex, which is not possible.
So $n=\Sigma_{i=0}^r|S(v,i)|\geq 1+(r-1)2+|S(v,r)|=2r-1+|S(v,r)|$.

This shows that $G$ has at least $2r$ vertices.

Your extra condition requires (for some $v$) that $|S(v,r)|=2$, leading to at least $2r+1$ vertices.

Comment: Hello sir, how did u conclude that $w$ will be a cut vertex in this case. I have doubt in following statement too : 
$n=|S(v,0)| +|S(v,1)| +|S(v,2)|+ \ldots + |S(v,r)|\geq 1+(r-1)2+|S(v,r)|=2r-1+|S(v,r)|$.
How the term $(r-1)2$ came in the RHS of $\geq$ inequality. Kindly help.

Comment: Sir, I got how you proved that $w$ will be a cut vertex. Can you please elaborate the summation term?

Comment: @monalisa: on the right side of the inequality, the term 1 corresponds to $i=0$, the term $(r-1)2$ corresponds to $i=1,\ldots,r-1$ and the term $|S(v,r)|$ corresponds to $i=r$.

Comment: Sir, do you mean to say S(v,1) = 1, S(v,2) = 2 and so on such that S(v,r-1) = r-1. I can't get why 2 is multiplied here.

Comment: @monalisa: No, $S(v,1)\geq2, \ldots, S(v,r-1)\geq2$ (since the answer explains why value 1 is not possible).